# What is the measure of the angle x in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference:In figure ABCD is a parallelogram and the triangles APB, AQD and CRD are equilateral. Find x. (answer: $120^\circ$)

[image]

My progress:
I found the following links and put it in the drawing
$AF = FC\\
BF = FD\\
\measuredangle QEG = 60^o\\
\measuredangle DAC = \measuredangle ACB$

but I can't finish..

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're also demanding that the two blue angles in the first diagram be equal, which will not be the case in general. (Draw ABCD as a square if you want to verify this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that $\angle PAQ = \angle BAD$, $AP = AB$, $AQ = AD$.

So $\triangle PAQ \cong \triangle BAD \ $ and hence $\angle AQP = \angle ADB$

Similarly show that $\triangle RDQ \cong \triangle CDA$ and so, $\angle DQR = \angle CAD$

But $\angle ADB + \angle CAD = 180^\circ - x \ $ (see $\triangle AOD$ where $O$ is the point of intersection of diagonals in the parallelogram $ABCD$)

That leads to,

$\angle PQR = x = 180^\circ - x + 60^\circ  \implies x = 120^\circ$